# Overwrite while querying firebase

Tags: android, firebase

```
collection->
    |
   phonenumber1->passkey1->tokenid1
    |    
   phonebumber2->passkey2->tokenid2
```

code for entering data

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> map=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String,String> passkey=new HashMap<String, String>();
passkey.put(my_passkey,tokenId);
map.put(phonetxt,passkey);
firebase.child("collection").setValue(map, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
@Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
}
```

I am implementing above code in order to make a json tree some thing like above.but whenever i run this code it keeps overwriting my entries.
when i run the code for first time :-

```
collection->
        |
       phonenumber1->passkey1->tokenid1
```

second  time i run the code it gives me:-

```
collection->
        |
       phonenumber2->passkey2->tokenid2
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are overwriting the 'collection' node each time you run it so it overwrites what's already there. To fix, add another .child. i.e. firebase.child("collection").child(phoneNumVar).SetValue(...). phoneNumVar being a variable that contains the phone numbers.

Comment: thanx ,this worked like a charm..

Comment: Great! Glad that was the issue - converted to answer so you can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the 'collection' node each time you run it so it overwrites what's already there.

To fix, add another .child. i.e.

firebase.child("collection").child(phoneNumVar).SetValue(...).

phoneNumVar being a variable that contains the phone numbers